# Creat App load database is available in android

Tags: android

I have a database data.db creat by tool SQliteAdministrator
I want load data.db,What should I do

data.db data available!
you give me an example of this

I have to use:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    final String MY_CELLS = "create table mycells (" + "mcc integer,"
            + "mnc integer," + "lac integer," + "cid integer)";

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.TABLE_FEMTO);
    db.execSQL(FEMTO_TABLE);
```

}

in the upgrade-method you can use sql-commands like insert, delete, update etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand, you want to use an existing databse in your Android app ...

A simple search would gave you the following results :

- http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
- [How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application)